# How can I group socket connections by the client application instance they propagated from?

Tags: c#, sockets, architecture, tcp

Most recently I have been working on an application that is leveraged by  a TCP [client-server model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)  ([reverse connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_connection)).

In order to improve the performance of long-running operations, I have made it so that a single instance of the client application can make a number of outgoing socket connections to the server.

When the server application accepts an incoming connection, the child socket representing that connection is encapsulated in a new instance of a class called a `ServerChildSocket`.

I need some way to effectively group all of the `ServerChildSocket` instances that propagated from the same *client application instance* but I am struggling to develop a working approach let alone a good approach.

My objective is to group `ServerChildSocket` instances accordingly in a class similar to this...

```
class UserState
{
     ServerChildSocket MainConnection {get; set;}
     ServerChildSocket FileDownloadConnection {get; set;}
     ServerChildSocket VoiceChatConnection {get; set;}
}
```

How can I identify which connections originated from the same client application instance and then assign the connection to an instance of the `UserState` class accordingly?

---

I believe that the client application would need to send some preliminary information about the connections' intent (main connection? download connection? etc.) as soon as the connection has been established. I am struggling to think of a way to bring this all together, though.

Comment: check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19307/Generic-TCP-IP-Client-Server (the code is old now and many improvements can be made but the approach should give you some ideas)

Comment: Are you concerned with conveying the client-id and connection purpose or organizing this information in a data structure on the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include the assignment of a "client id" from the server to each client in your protocol and also the idea of tagging each connection based on its intended use.

When the client makes its main connection to the server the relevant part of the handshake would look like this:

```
             CLIENT                          SERVER

           Type = Main    =============>
           Id   = null

                          <=============    Id = 123
```

Then, when the client makes additional side-channel connections it will include the id returned by the server in the initial handshake:

```
             CLIENT                          SERVER

           Type = Chat    =============>
           Id   = 123
```

This way the server knows what client each accepted connection belongs to and there is also no danger of accidental collisions (the server will not assign the same id to multiple clients). Finally, you can make the id as large and unpredictable as you like in order to guard against clients spoofing the sidechannel connections of one another.

Comment: A securely generated random Guid would be good as ID. And the server must make sure that the ID sent is actually registered.

Comment: This looks very promising. Do you know of any open-source applications of a similar nature that implement such a handshake? No worries if not.

Comment: @CasterTroy: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Managed to develop a working solution based on this answer earlier in the week. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you are seeking is something like server side session management.
A description of architectural road map, implementation in Web Servers could be seen [hear](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416137/Understanding-Session-Management-Techniques-in-ASP). 
*Stan Kirk* have contributed an advanced post called [C# SocketAsyncEventArgs High Performance Socket Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod) , handling `UserToken` acknowledgment by session-id.
I think combining the implementation of Stan Kirk to create the session-id and storing it in a  concurrent-Hash-Map, like [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) (TKey as session-id, TValue as UserState) will help you.